# runc: how to start stopped container

Tags: linux-containers, runc

I am playing with raw containers. And I do not see a way to rerun a container that is currently stopped.

```
# runc run nginx --detach
# runc kill nginx
```

as the result I have got the stopped container.

How to run it again without delete?

This does not work:

```
# runc start nginx
ERRO[0000] cannot start a container that has stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can not `restart` a container once you have killed it.

The possible solution here is to `delete` and then `create` is again.